# How to reset the password in Django

Tags: django

I am using the password reset function in django for resetting the password.

```
settings.py:
-------------
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxx@99'
EMAIL_PORT = 587

urls.py:
---------
url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView, name='password_reset.html'),

views.py:
---------
def password_reset(request):
    print ("entered the fn")
    subject = "please change the password"
    message = "please reset it"
    to_list = ['xxxxxxxx@gmail.com']
    send_mail(subject, message, to_list, fail_silently=True)
```

but when i am entering the email to reset it i am getting the following error:

```
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsX\n5.7.14 CBaTzAk4DIKFcdsgkGIv0Lgp1EdvehV4fsLoBw-Ix7_G5jQXYN8Ug0HFH-jO6UIjiar2nC\n5.7.14 Nd2dL4HXSYN4Oiazo88whyg8bSkbikpebbnb8E9JzDNTPT8s2b4vAgWrD87xNVpe1DGE94\n5.7.14 VGnf_nPjyyVW1R7xJaYpl8s23hB8fPcEYiPugPUPKjusMagyaOjZNG7v> Please log\n5.7.14 in via your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 d6sm10486629pfg.47 - gsmtp')
```

Comment: it an error with your gmail account .might have to enable less secure app in the dashboard please use this link [https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps]

Comment: I have enabled but still getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are being stymied by GMail's account security features.

You need to likely follow these instructions:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=1-636656345878819046-1400238651&rd=1#cantsignin

This guide might also be of assistance:  https://www.lifewire.com/get-a-password-to-access-gmail-by-pop-imap-2-1171882